# Make a 2D table appear as 1D table of its columns one after the other for mobiles

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I'm developping a website. Everything looks good from Desktop, but the tables I got are pretty large for a phone, so they appear with a slider which I want to avoid.
My question is the following :

Given a table presented as follows :

A   B   C   D

E   F   G   H

I   J   K   L

I want it to appear column after column like this :

A

E

I

B

F

J

C

.

.

In my css file I use only the following property so changes only affect small screens

```
@media 

only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example of what you could do. Not sure if it's best practice.

```
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

tr,
tbody {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-item: center; // used for example aligns items horizontally center
  justify-content: space-between; // used for example aligns items with space between
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 33%;
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  td {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}
```

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since you are new to html/css i'd suggest you have a play here: https://flexboxfroggy.com/ as it might explain how flex is working.

EDIT: If the solution works, use classes instead of tags.